# How to enable a button if the condition is true in android?

Tags: android

I have 4 xml named a1,a2 and a3 then I also have a main xml. In a1 there's an editText and an ok button, in a2 there's an ok button which is "disabled". Now, what I want to happen is when the data entered in a1 is correct, it will proceed to a2 then the "disabled" button there should now be "enabled". Now what happened on my program is, it's already running except for the button in a2 is getting enabled but it will return immediately into being disabled. How can I prevent it from getting disabled after it's been enabled? I'm new in android so please explain it as simple as it can be. Thanks in advance.

here's my code

Main Activity.java

```
package com.example.myact1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnExit);
    btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });


    Button page1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    page1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), a1.class);
   startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);


    }

});

}
```

}

MainActivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnExit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
    android:text="Exit" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnExit"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnExit"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:text="enter" />
```

a1 xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btna1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="155dp"

    android:text="Enter" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/eta1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btna1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

a1.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.a1);

    Button page1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btna1);
    page1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText a1et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eta1);
            String a1 = a1et.getText().toString();
            if (a1.equalsIgnoreCase("abcde")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), a2.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

                //enables the button in a2
                setContentView(R.layout.a2);
                Button stage2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btna2);
                stage2.setClickable(true);
                stage2.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

here's the code of my a2.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.a2);
    }
}
```

a2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btna2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:text="enter" />
```

Comment: why you change the layout of your activity ? just use two separated Activities , and then to enable the button you call `btn.setClickable(true)`and the disable it , pass false instead of true to she same method

Answer (score 1):

Also add

```
stage2.setEnabled(true);
```

Right below:

```
Button stage2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btna2);
stage2.setClickable(true);
```

**EDIT** After seeing all of your code, here are two corrections I did to your code so that it will work:

Remove this part of the code in `a1.java`:

```
//enables the button in a2
setContentView(R.layout.a2);
Button stage2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btna2);
stage2.setClickable(true);
stage2.setEnabled(true);
```

Remember that we decided to use new activity and not to change the `contentView` of the current one? Because you had this code the button appeared enabled for a short while before it became disabled once more.

Change the code of `a2.java#onCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.a2);
    Button stage2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btna2);
    stage2.setEnabled(true);    
}
```

Here you were not enabling the button and that was your problem. Rendering a2 `Activity` you overwrite the view you already rendered in a1 `Activity` with a new one. One that has the button disabled once more. I correct that with this code.

Comment: I already tried that. the button is already enabling but after that it becomes disabled again. I think after button is set enabled, the page reloads again and set the button back to being disabled. please help I'm stuck on this

Comment: @Bech Basically I would join Houcine's urge for using multiple activities. Otherwise you will use the changes in the `setContentView` for sure if the app process gets killed and the system restores your activity. Maybe you also call the `onCreate` method somewhere else? What is the superclass of your `Activity`?

Comment: is there a way to stop the page from loading again? so that the button will not set back in disable mode.

Comment: @Bech I don't advise you to, because that might leave your application hanging, without displaying anything. Can you please post the whole code of the activity?

Comment: @Bech and what happens now

Comment: what happens if I supply the correct data in a1 and press ok, I will be directed in a2 then the ok button in a2 will be enabled but it will turn to being disabled again. How can I prevent it from getting disabled?

Comment: @Bech Please post the content view you set for `a2`

Comment: @Bech: Hmm, but this is not actually a valid Android xml file. You don't have the wrapper layout and the Android namespace defined in it. See how such layout should look like here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html e.g.

Comment: @Bech Overall you get me wrong. I am not pointing mistakes without a reason I am trying to find the reason for your problem. I suppose things did not fix after the last change? Tell me how the button looks like after becoming disabled again: does it become shaded? Or is it that it just does not respond to clicks?

Comment: is there any way how to prevent it from getting back to disable/shaded?

Comment: @Bech: ah sorry i forgot about your case. I can not figure out your problem. Can you post all the code of the xmls and those two activities?

Comment: updated sir I only have 1 xml and 1 java for a1 as well as in a2

Comment: @Bech please post the whole java files

Comment: that's all my project contains sir

Comment: also, my a3 contains only a blank page in which if i click the button in a2 if it is enabled, it will direct the user in a3 page.

Comment: @Bech: you've got to be kidding! java file without a declaration of class? Only a method? The first line being `@Override`?This will not compile at all.

Comment: there. sorry I'm new here in android

Comment: all I want to happen is when I supply or enter the right data on my a1, it will direct me in a2 and the button there must now be in enable mode. what happened is that whenever I enter the correct data in the edit text in a1, it directs me in a2 then the button there enables and suddenly it will turn to disabled state again. how can I  fix that?

Comment: @Bech: still not what i needed. I guess the code is not pretty confidential. Can you please share somewhere the whole project you have? Place a link to the archive here afterwards.

Comment: here's my sample project. I want to try it first before I code it on my main project. http://www.sendspace.com/file/9358jg

Comment: @Bech No sorry. I had not received notification for your previous post. I will look into it right now.

Comment: ok sir I already have posted the download link on my last comment.

Comment: thanks for that it fix my problem on the project that I send to you but when I tried it on my main project, sad to say it doesn't work.